# How to mount a GS-connected phone as a local directory?

Tags: mount, sftp

I've used GSConnect to mount my phone in Ubuntu 18.04.  A phone directory appears in folder /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.0.110,port=1741/9C33-6BBD/

I'm using Spyder (Python) to process data that's streaming off of the phone.  I'd like to do it directly on the data on the phone, although that's just an intermediate step.

When I attempt to navigate Spyder to that directory it times out or gives an error.

When I attempt to mount the sftp host as a directory I get a generic failure error:

```
mount: /home/eljamoquio/Desktop: bind /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.0.110,port=1741/9C33-6BBD failed.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears as if it actually worked with one of the mount combos I've tried.